# What does 「ニゴでした」mean?

Tags: meaning, words, word-usage

I was reading an article at Tomojuku. [Link](http://www.tomojuku.com/blog/tekuruteiku4/)

At the very end of the article, it says,

> ではでは　ニゴでした。

What does ニゴでした mean ? I searched online but I couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: Probably the name/nickname of the author of the article is ニゴ.

Answer (score 5):

That is because the teachers's name is 仁子{にご} 真裕美{まゆみ}.

> 「(Name) + でした。」

is a common ending greeting for online writings, radio programs, etc.

仁子's profile is here:

http://www.tomojuku.com/blog/