# What does (name) でした mean?

Tags: phrases

During one of Yui's concerts I heard her say,

> ありがとうございました。Yuiでした。

https://clyp.it/0lsklv1i

What does it mean here?

I only know りんごでした = it **was** an apple.
So it doesn't make sense for her to be saying I **was** Yui.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60219/9831

Comment: That is more than just "related".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be odd if, in English, a singer ended a concert with 'Thank you all so much for attending. This **has been** Yui, and I'll see you again next time,' would it?

Comment: I guess that makes sense. looking at my playlist, that track is in the last part. although she still did one last song, it's still the end for that concert.
ありがとう！